# Recursive calculation for stock Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have a problem with calculating the stock for articles. I am using a matrix in which the rows are the articles and the columns are firstly days of the week, and then each column is delivered, sold.
My goal is to find the 'predicted' stock for each day.
I have an initial value for the stock for example 10, and I have received 5 more, and sold 3, so the stock for Monday would be 10 + 5 - 3 = 12, the next day I have received 10 and sold 2, so on Tuesday the stock would be 12 + 10 - 2 = 20 and so on.

I have the following DAX but it is not working, it is only calculating the stock for each day separately:

```
Stock (KG) = 
IF(
    SUM(Warengruppen[Week day]) = 0,
    CALCULATE(Warengruppen[Init stock] + Warengruppen[Quantity D AVG (KG)]-Warengruppen[Quantity S AVG (KG)]),
    CALCULATE(
        Warengruppen[Init stock] +
        CALCULATE(Warengruppen[Quantity D AVG (KG)] - Warengruppen[Quantity S AVG (KG)], 
        Warengruppen[Week day] >= 0) 
    )
)
```

Thanks for the help.

The table looks like this:
Article X initial stock 5
Article Y initial stock 10

```
               |Monday|         |Tuesday|       |Wednesday|
         |Del.| Sold.| Stock|   |Del.| Sold.| Stock|  |Del. |Sold.| Stock|
```

|Article X |   10|    5 |    10 |     2|    5 |    7 |     3|    2 |      8|
|Article Y  |  10 |   0 |    20 |     0 |   20|    0 |     0   |  1 |     -1|

Comment: Add some sample/dummy data to your question and desired output;

Comment: Maybe it would get easier if you pivot the table? Just a suggestion.

Comment: This is supposed to be a measure in the matrix visual, correct? Not a calculated column in `Warengruppen` table?

Comment: Yes, it is supposed to be a measure that is dependable of itself based on the previous step.